# Issues in Manual OpenCV4Android SDK setup

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

After the import step on this page: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#import-opencv-library-and-samples-to-the-eclipse

I keep getting the following errors like in a popup in Eclipse:

> Building workspace: Errors occurred during the build. Errors running
>   builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Library -
>   @OPENCV_VERSION@'. java.lang.NullPointerException Errors running
>   builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - 15
>   puzzle'. java.lang.NullPointerException Errors running builder
>   'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample -
>   camera-calibration'. java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Cleaning all projects: Errors occurred during the build. Errors
>   running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'OpenCV Library -
>   @OPENCV_VERSION@'. Resource '/OpenCV Library - @OPENCV_VERSION@/bin'
>   does not exist. Resource '/OpenCV Library - @OPENCV_VERSION@/bin' does
>   not exist. I followed the warning and note given at the bottom as
>   well, but that did help.

My OpenCV4Android SDK version is 2.4.9.

Comment: If you are unable to get OpenCV4Android to work and you are at a point where you can consider alternatives, take a look at JavaCV.  I just finished a CV proof of concept app and found JavaCV easier to get going with.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely check out JavaCV sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did both of the following together:

Set NDKROOT for all projects individually even though the environment variable existed in my bashrc.

Switched to OpenCV4Android SDK version 2.4.8

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem -- I didn't wind up needing to switch to OpenCV4Android 2.4.8, but deleting my 2.4.9 directory and re-unzipping it and going through the steps from scratch seemed to fix everything.  I'm sure I just corrupted some files, and re-extracting my SDK fixed it.

So long story short:

Make sure you follow EVERY step in the tutorial:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

Make SURE that when you import the sample projects that you do it from the ROOT of the SDK directory -- not from the sample directory -- otherwise you miss the library.

Make SURE that you don't extract your OpenCV directory into a directory with spaces in the path (such as "My Documents").

And if you're wrestling it with a while and you can't seem to get it working, then don't hesitate to quit eclipse, delete your workspace, delete your OpenCV directory, and re-extract from the downloaded zip file and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same frustrating problem, I had to do two steps (different again!):

1. Open Properties for the Open CV library project (mine was OpenCV Library - 2.4.10), go to **Android** -> **Project Build Target**, and select a target name. (This is mentioned in the tutorial.)
2. Still in the Properties dialog, go to **Java Build Path** -> **Source**, at the bottom where it says **Default output folder:** mine said "*OpenCV Library - 2.4.10/cls*" - I changed this to "*OpenCV Library - 2.4.10/bin*"

And now it's building without errors.